# Angularjs if-then-else construction in expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat, ternary-operator

Can I somehow use if-then-else construction (ternary-operator) in angularjs expression, for example I have function $scope.isExists(item) that has to return bool value.
I want something like this,

```
<div ng-repeater="item in items">
    <div>{{item.description}}</div>
    <div>{{isExists(item) ? 'available' : 'oh no, you don't have it'}}</div>
</div>
```

I know that I can use function that returns string, I'm interesting in possibility of using if-then-else construction into expression.
Thanks.

Comment: Check out [`ng-switch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch)

Comment: Since 1.2 this is now supported.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Angular expressions do not support the ternary operator before 1.1.5, but it can be emulated like this:

```
condition && (answer if true) || (answer if false)
```

So in example, something like this would work:

```
<div ng-repeater="item in items">
    <div>{{item.description}}</div>
    <div>{{isExists(item) && 'available' || 'oh no, you don't have it'}}</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Angular 1.1.5 added support for ternary operators:

```
{{myVar === "two" ? "it's true" : "it's false"}}
```

Comment: Does && need to be escaped?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey no you must not. You could (if possible for your project) use the ternary operator like I explained in my answer to the topic question.

Comment: @Sebastian What about `<` and `>` as comparison operators?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey No problem also, {{1>0?true:false}} or {{1>0}} whatever you like. {{1>0}} works also in 1.0.8, but ternary operator does not.

Comment: This is still a great answer since it works inside the settings of angular-ui components (while ternary operator does not work there on some reason). Maybe this helps someone struggling to set angular-ui parameters

Answer (score 41):

You can use ternary operator since version 1.1.5 and above like demonstrated in this little [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6dgGxUefWfR5ovNqGrDz?p=preview) (example in 1.1.5):

For history reasons *(maybe plnkr.co get down for some reason in the future)* here is the main code of my example:

```
{{true?true:false}}
```

Comment: For history reasons (maybe plnkr.co get down for some reason in the future) here is the main code of my example: `{{true?true:false}}`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you, almost used a filter to do this.

Comment: @IgorCh: You might want to update the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 25):

You can easily use ng-show such as :

```
    <div ng-repeater="item in items">
        <div>{{item.description}}</div>
        <div ng-show="isExists(item)">available</div>
        <div ng-show="!isExists(item)">oh no, you don't have it</div>
    </div>
```

For more complex tests, you can use ng-switch statements :

```
    <div ng-repeater="item in items">
        <div>{{item.description}}</div>
        <div ng-switch on="isExists(item)">
            <span ng-switch-when="true">Available</span>
            <span ng-switch-default>oh no, you don't have it</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: An advantage of doing it at the element level like this instead of inside the expression is that you can customize the style and content of the different options much more.

Comment: Yes, I know about this functionality it could help, but I don't want to add extra div to the document. but also thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line.

```
{{corretor.isAdministrador && 'YES' || 'NÂO'}}
```

Usage in a `td` tag:

```
<td class="text-center">{{corretor.isAdministrador && 'Sim' || 'Não'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to check if a key exist in an array in angular way and landed here on this question. In my Angularjs 1.4 ternary operator worked like below

`{{ CONDITION ? TRUE : FALSE }}`

hence for the **array key exist** i did a simple JS check

Solution 1 : `{{ array['key'] !== undefined ? array['key'] : 'n/a' }}`

Solution 2 : `{{ "key" in array ? array['key'] : 'n/a' }}`