# angular: toggle text of button based on boolean value in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is a simple way to change the text in a button element based on a boolean value?

pseudo code:

```
<button> some text OR some other text </button>
```

I read this: [Angularjs if-then-else construction in expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584346/angularjs-if-then-else-construction-in-expression)

and this regarding ng-switch: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Neither seems to work using bool value from model

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Should use like that :

```
<button> {{ cond_vall == true ? 'Case 1' : 'Case 2' }}</button>
```

Comment: I'm having a weird spacing issue with this approach, see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456600/ionic-weird-spacing

Comment: @RockOnGom: What's the point of comparing a boolean to `true`? This works just fine: `{{ cond_vall ? 'Case 1' : 'Case 2' }}`

Comment: Use `cond_vall === true`

Answer (score 15):

I guess it depends on what the text is that you are trying to show. If you have control over what the text is in the controller, you can bind the text to a scope variable and set it in the controller so you don't have to put any logic in the view. Something like:

```
<button>{{someScopeVarWithYourString}}</button>
```

Otherwise, you can use an ng-if or ng-show on the boolean condition.

```
<button ng-show="someBoolValue">some text</button>
<button ng-show="!someBoolValue">some other text</button>
```

Comment: I ended up doing exactly what you mentioned in the first option. perhaps this is the cleanest approach.  second approach toggles between two different buttons and I want to keep one button.

Comment: I agree. The "cleanest" approach is to do it from the model. and the UI view is just a "dump" reflection of the model. This is the idea behind separate model / view in the first place

Comment: Yea, it is. Keeps your view less cluttered also.

Answer (score 11):

Because I needed to use a filter (translate filter) for the button text, the following solution worked best for me:

```
<button>
    <span> {{ condition ? 'some_text' : 'some_Other_text' | translate }}</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only parenthesis seem required when combining `Angular 8 LTS`, `Typescript 3.5` and `ngx-bootstrap`

```
<button type="button" class="btn"> {{ ( boolVar ? 'text' : 'other text')  | translate }} </button>
```

Comment: The question is for AngularJS not Angular

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{message}} <br />
    <button ng-click="changeMessage(message)">Change Message</button>
  </div>
</div>

var module = angular.module("myModule", []);
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
$scope.message = "Hello World";
  $scope.changeMessage = function(value) {
  if(value==="Hello World"){
  $scope.message = "Hello Universe!";
  }else{
    $scope.message = "Hello World";
  }

  };
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Answer (score 0):

```
xyz.component.html

<button (click)="isCoreComponentUpdate ? onSubmit(): updateCoreComponent()">{{isCoreComponentUpdate ? 'Update' : 'Add'}}</button>
```

```
xyz.component.ts
isCoreComponentUpdate: Boolean= false;
```

when we want to use same button as Add and edit when we open add popup and edit popup that time this code will helpfull

where 'isCoreComponentUpdate' Boolean value based on that we are showing label and enabling action.