# Ionic weird spacing

Tags: css, ionic-framework

When I use the following code to display a header, the **title**  gets a weird left/right styling.

Anybody knows what's wrong with it? Thanks!

```
<ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">BLE Demo</h1>
    <button class="button button-positive">
        {{connectStatus == false ? "Connect" : "Disconnect" }}
    </button>
</ion-header-bar>
```

If I change the line `{{connectStatus == false ? "Connect" : "Disconnect" }}` to `{{connectStatus}}`, then the styling disappears.

**Update:** Check this example code made by @Microsmsm: http://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/ZQZyVp

[image]

Comment: What is the desired lay-out? The button without the `right` property?

Comment: `align-title` attribute in `<ion-header-bar>`  set the alignment of title in ionic. Something like `<ion-header-bar align-title="center">` for centering it. `left` or `right` are also available values.

Comment: The problem appears on the title: the <h1> element gets a "right" styling when the button element has `{{connectStatus == false ? "Connect" : "Disconnect" }}` instead of `{{connectStatus}}` in it,

Comment: I think that is not an angular issue. Can you upload your page to internet. Check your CSS style.

Comment: You can check this one made by @Microsmsm http://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/ZQZyVp It's not a CSS issue, as the left/right styling is added to the element directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code [as that](http://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/ZQZyVp).
You change

```
{{connectStatus == false ? "Connect" : "Disconnect" }}
```

to

```
{{connectStatus == true ? "Connect" : "Disconnect" }}
```

to get your effect done

Comment: Compare your sketch with this one: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgBrre, you can see that the <h1> element has a weird left/right styling in the one you created. And the only way to remove it is changing `{{connectStatus == false ? "Connect" : "Disconnect" }}` to `{{connectStatus}}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by following a standard blank template. Using ion-nav-bar, and not specifying the h1 element myself.

Apparently ionic tries to center the title by adding a left/right styling to the element depending on how wide are the other elements(the button in this example) to the left/right. But the way of calculation is pretty weird, not depending on how much content is actually being displayed, but how long the template script is.

So in this case `{{connectStatus == false ? "Connect" : "Disconnect" }}` is much longer than `{{connectStatus}}`, and ionic gives 333px to the left and right for the former, and 124px to the later. Even if the amount of text being displayed are not much different.

Not sure if there's a way to fix this problem as it is. I'll stick with ion-nav-bar for the time being.