# Ternary not working properly for function call in angular expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to call a function on $last in ng-repeat, if I use,

```
   div(ng-repeat="note in notes")
    li: {{note}}
    {{$last ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```

It prints false only on last li element, but for the same if I call a function instead of 'true', like below

```
   div(ng-repeat="note in notes")
    li: {{note}}
    {{$last ? update() : 'false' }}
```

the function is called for each loop.

For your information, I had tried "&&" kind of solution given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584346/angularjs-if-then-else-construction-in-expression)

```
{{$last && update() || '' }}
```

also, but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything obvious wrong so maybe error is somewhere else in your code. See the following:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.notes = ['Note 1','Note 2'];
  $scope.update = function () {
    return 'i haz updated!1';
  };
});
```

---

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="note in notes">
    <li>
      {{note}} - isLast:{{$last ? 'true' : 'false'}} - {{$last ? update() : '???'}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

[image: imgur]

---

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DwCpcC

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4eXzOsnRl8j8DcEWqLV?p=preview)

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="note in notes">
       {{ note }}
       {{ $last ? update():''}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why `$index` when we have `$first` and `$last`? Besides that, how is this answer any different?