# Angular JS with If shorthand in HTML possible?

Tags: html, angularjs

So I have following code:

```
div(ng-repeat="item in list")
    div(class="({{item.note_type}} == 1)?\"critical\":\"\"")
```

Is it possible to have the `If?:` inside html combined with AngularJS?

Comment: ON my side such an expression work perfect:`ng-class="event.IsHoliday?'event-text-holiday':'event-leave-status-'+event.Status"`

Comment: Might be helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584346/angularjs-if-then-else-construction-in-expression

Comment: Many thanks both! I am a beginner in AngularJS too :)